# What does "Four-F." mean?

Tags: meaning, american-english

What did "Four-F." mean in the United States of the 1940s?

Here is the quote from [Catch-22](https://books.google.at/books?id=Xfze51E7TEoC&pg=PA48&lpg=PA48&dq=catch-22+%2B+i+was+four+f&source=bl&ots=uXBZjDzILz&sig=ACfU3U0KCAgXx11Hc1UlT0NeGA4gvkSxpQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjRuN7T0onhAhXk0aYKHXY-BqIQ6AEwEXoECAQQAQ#v=onepage&q=catch-22%20%2B%20i%20was%20four%20f&f=false):

> They had to send a guy from the draft board around to look me over. **I was Four-F.** I had examined myself pretty thoroughly and discovered that I was unfit for military service

Comment: Nit: 4-F remained part of the military and social lingo until, post Viet Nam, Congress cancelled the Selective Service Act(s).

Comment: When I saw the question, before I saw context, I misremembered 4H(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/4-H )  and thought instead of "Head, Heart, Hands, and Health", the letter stood for Family, Faith, Farm and Friendship."  Oops. :)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

It's a classification for military service. 4-F means "Registrant not acceptable for military service." See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selective_Service_System#Classifications

The context clue here you might have used to deduce an area of inquiry would be the reference to a "draft board", which is part of the Selective Service System that determines the eligibility and thus the classification of potential draftees.

Comment: yep, or straight from the horse’s mouth: https://www.sss.gov/Classifications

Comment: Specifically, 4-F commonly implied you were ineligible for medical reasons. The character in the book who said that was a doctor; the implication is that he just didn't want to be drafted and so said "as a doctor, I find that I am medically unfit."

Comment: @cpast PLEASE make that an answer! OP may never see the comment thread here, and I think it's crucial to understand that!

Comment: Specifically for the sake of catch 22, it means he's medically unfit for mental health reasons